How to best run Inkscape on Ubuntu 24.04 (crashes on startup)
After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04, I had to reinstall Inkscape, which for some reason was removed during the upgrade. I've tried three methods to install, none of them fully successful:

sudo apt install inkscape => Result: inkscape does not launch (segmentation fault, probably LP bug #2079921)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable && sudo apt install inkscape => Result: inkscape does not launch (segmentation fault, same bug as above?)
sudo snap install inkscape => Result: inkscape launches (yay!). But it cannot export files (exporting to PDF was my main use case). The widget to select a file name to export does not work in the snap package, it does nothing upon clicking on it. And without a file name, the export throws an error. Same as Inkscape snap package unable to export png.

How do people use Inkscape in Ubuntu 24.04 at all? What are the next steps? Flatpak? Build from source?
Notes:

I've noticed there is an additional ppa:inkscape.dev/stable-daily but the fact that this supposedly daily PPA hasn't been updated for the last 4 months makes me think it's no longer maintained either.
I've read bug reports about Inkscape crashing in Wayland with some tablets. I've disconnected my tablet, with the same result (crash).


For what it's worth, I don't have that export problem with the flatpak version

Thanks for testing. I have a solution now, but good to know Inkscape works when installed as a Flatpak.

After lots of trial and error and research, I found out that there is yet another PPA with packages built from Inkscape's main branch. Installing the inkscape-trunk package from there solved the issue for me:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/trunk
sudo apt install inkscape-trunk

I hope this can help other Inkscape users in Ubuntu 24.04.
